# How do I determine if current server time isn't within a specified range using Python ?

Tags: python

I need to check in Python if the current time on the server isn't in the time range of 22:00PM - 04:00AM.

What is the correct way to write this code ?

Thanks !

Comment: It depends. Do you write the server side or the client side?

Comment: @YotamSalmon I am writing the server side. What I tried so far is to calculate the hours but only on the same day when the start time was smaller than then end time. My problem is the transition to a new day.

Comment: Ah, ok. So if that's the case, take a look at @jia hilegass 's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below:

```
import time
def isWithinRange():
    hour = time.localtime(time.time()).tm_hour
    return hour >= 22 or hour <= 4
```

Comment: First of all thanks, secondly why do I need the                  elif hour <= 4: statement ? there's a way to combine them to just one IF statement so I run commands inside ?

Comment: Let me modify it to a function so that you can use it easily.

Comment: Which indent do you use? Tab or space? You need to modify it.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I appreciate your time and effort to help me. It works now.